# Magento Submit Order button not forwarding after security patch update

Tags: magento-1.7, credit-card, authorize.net, payment-method

Magento Submit Order button not forwarding when Credit Card (Authorize.net Direct Post) payment method selected after Magento security patch update

Few days ago I have installed [Security patch 8788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788) (PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.7.0.2_v2-2016-10-14) for Magento ver 1.7.0.2 successfully. But I found that, Order is not submitting when the Credit Card (Authorize.net Direct Post) payment method is selected from the checkout page. When hit submit to finish the checkout, all it does it keeps loading and nothing happens. See below attachment.

[image: Screenshot of the checkout page]

N.B: I didn't found such type of problem in the list of [SUPEE-6788 TECHNICAL DETAILS](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details). I have checked the system.log and exception.log but nothing found.

Also I have checked that the old version works perfectly before security patch update.

Any ideas why this might be occurring? Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console log error, It seems like Checkout ajax request is not working.